# Is there a way to use a conditional statement in an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, conditional-statements

I have an XML file that contains URLs.

I want to add cases because I need a different URL each time.

I know I can do this in Java, but I'd prefer not to change my Java code for now.

Comment: Well without changing Java code, you cannot do that!

Comment: XSLT is the logic counter part to XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML files contain data, not logic. So they can't hold conditions.

Comment: Actually: XML files hold data. So they can hold anything, including conditions. But XML doesn't DO anything with the data; that depends on whoever is processing it.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of `XML` is that it stores data only. There should be nothing except data itself,
so, you should make the conditional in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You may use XSLT but I guess you'll have to change code to handle it! XML is a data container, how to use and "see" (XPath for example) that data is managed by its consumer (to minimize changes you may simply expose the query in the XML file).

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to put conditions in your XML. For example, I have documents like this:

```
<p if="EU-user">VAT is not payable if you are registered for VAT in an EU country other than the UK</p>
```

Putting conditions like that in your data makes excellent sense. But it only makes sense if the recipient is capable of interpreting them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PMML (Predictive Modeling Markup Language)